# What is the first square in the sequence $4729494n+1$?

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

Today I found a strange phenomenon that I want to ask about.

If  $$f(n)=4729494n+1,$$
is square, where $n$ is positive integers. Then I found $n=4729492$, because  $$f(4729492)=4729493^2$$
In fact, note $$(x-1)(x+1)+1=x^2$$

Now  I conjecture: $$n_{\min}=4729492?$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's $n=17372$, because $4729494\cdot 17372 +1 = 286637^2$.

The question can be restated as solving $x^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 4729494$.

Since $4729494 =2 \cdot 3 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 29 \cdot 353$, you first solve $x^2 \equiv 1 \bmod p$ for each of these primes. The solution is of course $x \equiv \pm1 \bmod p$ and they can be combined using the Chinese remainder theorem. It's a lot of work to do by hand because there are $2^5$ [solutions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%3D1+mod+4729494) mod $4729494$, one for each combination of signs $\pm1$. It's easier to write a small program and search for the smallest solution of the original problem, which is what I did.

Comment: Thanks, +1.Nice example. then $n=17372$ is minumin of the value?

Comment: How prove this ?

Comment: @functionsug I assume by brute force. You check all the numbers below $17372$ and show that none produces a perfect square.